# Homology groups of genus $g$ Riemann surface with $n$ punctures.

Tags: homology-cohomology, riemann-surfaces, mayer-vietoris-sequence

I want to know whether one can compute $H_k(\Sigma_{g,n})$ with elementary methods like singular chain complex? By $\Sigma_{g,n}$ I mean a genus $g$ surface with $n$ circular holes. If not, I'm not familiar with the standard method, which is Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Could you please introduce me to a lecture or note that help me work this out? Or any link to the exact solution to this problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Not to be snarky, but if you don't know about the Mayer-Vietoris sequence then learning about using any range of standard texts of algebraic topology, for instance A. Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" seems like a good place to start. It is a fundamental tool of singular homology after all.

Comment: That being said, there is an elementary computation not using MV: Note that $\Sigma_{g, 1}$ deformation retracts onto $\bigvee_{i = 1}^{2g} S^1$ (this is immediate from the description of $\Sigma_g$ as a certain quotient of a $2n$-gon or the related fact that it admits a CW-structure with a single 2-cell with this wedge sum as 1-skeleton), and every further puncture just adds another copy of $S^1$ (for similar geometric reasons). The homology of a finite wedge sum of copies of $S^1$ you then hopefully understand.